# How to use a Wasm class compiled using EMScripten in Angular

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, webassembly, wasm-bindgen

I sucessfully generate a wasm module using emscripten.
A `.js` file is generated along a `.wasm` file.
Loading through node.js works like a charm. So far so good.

C++ bindings looks like this:

```
#include "worker.hpp"
#include <emscripten/bind.h>

using namespace emscripten;

// Binding code
EMSCRIPTEN_BINDINGS(Worker)
{
    class_<Worker>("Worker")
        .constructor<>()
        .function("Start", &Worker::Start)
        .function("GetGreetings", &Worker::GetGreetings);
}
```

Node.js code:

```
const fabricWorker = require('./build/fabric_wasm')

fabricWorker['onRuntimeInitialized'] = () => {
    var instance = new fabricWorker.Worker();
    instance.Start();
    console.log(instance.GetGreetings());
}
```

Now I'm trying to import it into an Angular component, but I can't find a way to do it. How to import a wasm class generated using emscripten into a component?